# pandas swap rows between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have basketball teams, each of which is in a pandas dataframe.   I would like to trade players.   The order of the players is important, so if a player comes out of the 2nd slot, I'd like the player going it to go into that same slot.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': [ 'Dwight_Howard ', 'Kobe_Bryant', 'Jameer_Nelson', 'Trevor_Ariza', 'Dirk_Nowitzki','Jordan_Hill', 'Eric_Gordon', 'Jeremy_Lin', 'Chandler_Parsons', 'Tim_Duncan'],
       'Pos': ['C','G','G','F','F','C','G','G','F','F'],
       'Value': [11, 8, 10, 15, 11,14, 7, 12, 13, 8]}


league = pd.DataFrame(data)
team1 = league[0:5:2]
team2 = league[1:6:2]

print team1
print team2
             Name Pos  Value
0  Dwight_Howard    C     11
2   Jameer_Nelson   G     10
4   Dirk_Nowitzki   F     11
           Name Pos  Value
1   Kobe_Bryant   G      8
3  Trevor_Ariza   F     15
5   Jordan_Hill   C     14
```

If I trade Howard for Hill, I'd like the teams to look like this:

```
             Name Pos  Value
5   Jordan_Hill     C     14
2   Jameer_Nelson   G     10
4   Dirk_Nowitzki   F     11
           Name Pos  Value
1   Kobe_Bryant   G      8
3  Trevor_Ariza   F     15
0  Dwight_Howard  C     11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @jezrael for the very helpful post.   I was able to distill it down into simply getting the value of the index for the two players from the league, and then swapping them in the league.  Since the teams are simply pointers to the league, that's all that needs to be done.   Here is the solution.  Again, thanks for the helpful pointers.

```
player1 = league[league.Name=='Dwight_Howard'].index.get_values()[0]
player2 = league[league.Name=='Jordan_Hill'].index.get_values()[0]
league.loc[[player1,player2],:] = league.loc[[player2,player1],:].values
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution swap values of `df` by index labels, what are names of players.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': [ 'Dwight_Howard', 'Kobe_Bryant', 'Jameer_Nelson', 'Trevor_Ariza', 'Dirk_Nowitzki','Jordan_Hill', 'Eric_Gordon', 'Jeremy_Lin', 'Chandler_Parsons', 'Tim_Duncan'],
       'Pos': ['C','G','G','F','F','C','G','G','F','F'],
       'Value': [11, 8, 10, 15, 11,14, 7, 12, 13, 8]}
player1 = 'Dwight_Howard'
player2 = 'Jordan_Hill'

league = pd.DataFrame(data)
team1 = league[0:5:2]
team2 = league[1:6:2]
print team1
print team2
#            Name Pos  Value
#0  Dwight_Howard   C     11
#2  Jameer_Nelson   G     10
#4  Dirk_Nowitzki   F     11
#           Name Pos  Value
#1   Kobe_Bryant   G      8
#3  Trevor_Ariza   F     15
#5   Jordan_Hill   C     14

#set new columns from index and columns name
league['Nameindex'] = league['Name'] 
league['idx'] = league.index
#set index from column Nameindex
league = league.set_index('Nameindex')
#swap values of dataframes by labels
league.loc[[player1,player2],:] = league.loc[[player2,player1],:].values
#set index from original index
league = league.set_index('idx')
#remove index name
del league.index.name
team1 = league[0:5:2]
team2 = league[1:6:2]
print team1
print team2
#            Name Pos  Value
#5    Jordan_Hill   C     14
#2  Jameer_Nelson   G     10
#4  Dirk_Nowitzki   F     11
#            Name Pos  Value
#1    Kobe_Bryant   G      8
#3   Trevor_Ariza   F     15
#0  Dwight_Howard   C     11
```